# Creating followups to Commerce Orders for each Line Item

Tags: rules, commerce

I had asked a question in another thread, and thought it might be helpful to create its own thread just in case it could be helpful to any other developers out there:

"I am trying to create a rule which follows up on existing orders of specific products. Each product has a different time interval for "follow up reminder", and my rule should trigger an email to be sent to a customer at a date which is calculated Order Creation Date + Follow Up Interval.

ie Order Creation + Value provided from Products in the order"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share how I solved this problem: I created a rule which is dependent on an Order's Status being "Completed". This rule runs a custom PHP script which loads the Completed order Entity, retrieves each Line item and checks for its field called "Follow-up", which gives a time value in weeks

Comment: If that field isn't empty, it runs some code to convert the time into seconds, choose a date value based on the order date + the followup time, and inserts a row into a database for EACH line item which requires a followup service. In order to send out mail for each particular followup, I created a cronjob using crontab directly on the server hosting the project. This simply runs each morning, checks the database to see if any of the rows have a date which matches "today", and subsequently retrieves the relevant information and sends the customer the appropriate followup notice!

Comment: If anyone wants some more info, snippets, etc, I would be happy to share any part of this code! It is somewhat lengthy, so I didn't want to paste it all.